# Почему не удаляется предыдущее сообщение с inline-клавиатурой?

Tags: python, aiogram, бот, telegram

Есть хендлер, присылающий 2 сообщения, первое без клавиатуры, второе с inline-клавиатурой:

```
@dp.message_handler(Text(equals='Задать вопрос'))
async def ask_ques_handler(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer(text="message 1",
                          parse_mode='HTML',
                          reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove())
    await message.answer(text="message 2",
                         reply_markup=get_base_ques_keyboard())
```

По нажатию на одну из этих кнопок в инлайн клавиатуре пользователь возвращается в главное меню, после чего предыдущие 2 сообщения должны быть удалены:

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda callback_query: callback_query.data == 'back_to_main_kb')
async def back_to_main_menu(callback: types.CallbackQuery):
    await bot.send_message(chat_id=callback.from_user.id,
                           text='Вы в главном меню',
                            reply_markup=main_menu_kb())
    await bot.delete_message(chat_id=callback.from_user.id, 
                             message_id=callback.message.message_id - 1)
    await bot.delete_message(chat_id=callback.from_user.id, 
                             message_id=callback.message.message_id - 2)
    await callback.answer()
```

Но удаляется только одно сообщение, вот это await message.answer(text="message 1", parse_mode='HTML', reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove())
Почему второе не удаляется?

Comment: Попробуй вместо ручного просчитывания ID'шника сообщении, т.е. `callback.message.message_id - 1`, сохранять где нибудь в памяте ID сообщении которые надо удалить.